# Is there a tex package which allows links syntax for common wikis/wiki syntaxes (MediaWiki, dokuwiki, ...)?

Tags: links, wiki

I've tried to get around the problem of getting wiki users to do as much as possible in the wiki I'm maintaining and overcome limitations of wiki and HTML markup with LaTeX (this basically means abusing the wiki revision facilities in order to avoid to force people how to use a versioning system - think about that what you want). There're quite a lot of good plugins out there for popular wiki software, like MediaWiki and dokuwiki, and LaTeX to HTML transformation is not dark magic in general, i.e. thinkable for an arbitrary number of other wikis.

It is only fun though if one is able to use the wiki link facilities (for both images or other resources and LaTeX includes) in the LaTeX markup when authoring wiki content in LaTeX which brings me to my question: Is there a LaTeX package which provides replacement of wiki links with links the LaTeX compiler can work with?

I can imagine that it probably would need some setup regarding a relative root and web server rewrite rules, but technically speaking it should be possible!